Let $ G $ be a Lie group and $ H $ a connected subgroup of $ G $. If $ N_G(H)/H $ is finite does that imply $ H $ must be closed in $ G $?
Let $ G $ be a Lie group and $ H $ a connected subgroup of $ G $. If $ N_G(H)/H $ is finite does that imply $ H $ must be closed in $ G $?
An obvious generalization of this claim is: If $ N_G(H)/H $ is closed in $ G/H $ does that imply $ H $ must be closed in $ G $? That is certainly false since we can take $ G=T^2 $ and $ H $ the line with irrational slope on the torus. Then $ N_G(H)=G $ and so $ N_G(H)/H=G/H $ is certainly closed in $ G/H $ but $ H $ is not closed in $ G $.
Motivation: I'm considering that the question Normalizer of connected subgroup might need the assumption that $ H $ is closed. But since $ N_G(H)/H $ is already assumed to be finite, and $ H $ assumed connected, perhaps that already implies that $ H $ must be closed?

This is clearly false. Maybe it is true for connected subgroups.

@MoisheKohan Ah ok let me add that $ H $ is connected, since that is already the assumption in the linked question that motivated this. Out of curiosity do you have any particular counterexample in mind for the case that $ H $ is not connected?

@Barri: Both assertions you've made are false.

So they are! I will delete my comment, thanks for checking

Yes, my example is $PSL(2,Q)<PSL(2,R)$.
